# I'm doing a truck braking model in my class and it will not compile or return the summary when it did compile. What did i do wrong?

Tags: python, physics

I would like somebody to look at my code. I have included a lot of comments in my code so hopefully it is easy to read and understand. The inputs (in order):

```
0.5
50
-28
0.05
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\jasmin\Jasmin\python\School Projects\Braking Model.py", line 59, in <module>
    truck_braking(react_time, init_vel, break_acc, user_chg_in_time)
  File "C:\jasmin\Jasmin\python\School Projects\Braking Model.py", line 42, in truck_braking
    print((int(time) - user_chg_in_time) * 100) / 100, '          ', math.ceil(((int(disp)) * 100) / 100), '          ', math.ceil(((int(speed)) * 100) / 100)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

The program uses Euler's method and is supposed to be something that non-programmers can use with ease.

Here it is:

```
#import math to use ceiling function
import math

#defined function

def truck_braking(react_time, init_vel, break_acc, user_chg_in_time):


    #assign variables to be referenced later
    chg_in_time = 0
    speed = init_vel
    disp = 0
    orig_disp = 0
    time = 0
    original_inputs = [react_time, init_vel, break_acc, user_chg_in_time]

    #prints table headings
    print('Time  Displacement  Speed/Velocity')

    #calculate outputs until truck stops
    while speed > 0:

    #calculate speed
    if time >= react_time:
        if break_acc < 0:
            speed = (speed + break_acc) * user_chg_in_time
        elif break_acc > 0:
            speed = (speed - break_acc) * user_chg_in_time
    else:
        speed = init_vel

    #calculate displacement
    disp += speed * time

    #change dt value
    chg_in_time = user_chg_in_time

    #adjust time value for next calculation/loop
    time += user_chg_in_time

    #creates table of values
    print((int(time) - user_chg_in_time) * 100) / 100, '          ', math.ceil(((int(disp)) * 100) / 100), '          ', math.ceil(((int(speed)) * 100) / 100)

    #arranges final outputs in list
    final_outputs = [(time - user_chg_in_time) * 100 / 100, math.ceil(((disp) * 100) / 100), math.ceil(((speed) * 100) / 100)]

    #returns summary # for stack overflow helper: this didn't work, it compiled but summary didn't show up
    return('The original inputs for reaction time, initial speed, breaking acceleration/decceleration, and change in time were ', original_inputs, '. The final outputs for time, displacement(distance), and speed respectively were ', final_outputs, '.')


#loops for as long as wants without having to run again
willingness = 'yes'
while willingness == 'yes':
    willingness = 'Would you like to do a calculation? Type "yes" for yes, and any other key for no.'
react_time = float(input('What is the reaction time?'))
init_vel = float(input('What was the initial velocity? (Speed at time = 0)'))
break_acc = float(input('What was the breaking speed of the truck? Can be positive or negative.'))
user_chg_in_time = float(input("What would you like the change in time to be? With the way Euler's method works, which is the method of calculation this program uses, the smaller this value is, the more accurate the calculations."))
truck_braking(react_time, init_vel, break_acc, user_chg_in_time)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to fix the indentation. The code in your function definition is not indented, and so will not run.

Comment: You should also mention in the question, what the problem with the program is, what error you get.

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Check your parentheses on that line - you are trying to divide `print(...)` by 100. Obviously, you cannot do this, since `print` returns `None`.

Comment: There are a lot of errors with this code both syntax, run this right now (as given) you will get an *Indentation Error* at `if time >= react_time:`, and logic errors - I would suggest splitting this into a few function so you can test each idea separately. Your current error is that your trying to divide `print` as your missing a closing `)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this totally unreadable line:

```
print((int(time) - user_chg_in_time) * 100) / 100, '          ', math.ceil(((int(disp)) * 100) / 100), '          ', math.ceil(((int(speed)) * 100) / 100)
```

Your parenthesis are off and you try to dive the return value of `print`, which is `None` by `100`.

Rearrange your code:

```
value1 = ((int(time) - user_chg_in_time) * 100) / 100
value2 = math.ceil(((int(disp)) * 100) / 100)
value3 = math.ceil(((int(speed)) * 100) / 100)
```

and use string formating for readable output:

```
print('{:15.2f} {:15.2f} {:15.2f}'.format(value1, value2, value3))
```

This is using Python's [string formatting capabilities](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html?highlight=mini#formatspec).

For example. This:

```
>>> '{:7.3f}'.format(3.5657676)
'  3.566'
```

formats a float with a total width of 7 and 3 decimals. Using multiple `{} {}` allows to have multiple values. `format` offer much more therefore this formatting is called [Formatting Mini Language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html?highlight=mini#formatspec).

After this changes it runs with my inputs.

Comment: Ok, I understand why but not what it's doing exactly. I just started with python late august, could you explain what that second snippet of code is doing and how it does it?

Comment: Added more explanation.

Comment: @JasminCallaway You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.